# I am trying to train a model but not working because a batch_size error in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am creating a deep learning model in google colab and I am coming to an issue when I am training my model and batch_size is throwing an error and the error is: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 34, 3) and (None, 3) are incompatible`

> One issue
> Error: IndexError: index 26 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 26

```
    # Store labels of dataset
labels = ['Ա', 'Բ', 'Գ', 'Դ', 'Ե', 'Զ', 'Է', 'Ը', 'Թ', 'Ժ', 'Ի', 'Լ', 'Խ', 'Ծ', 'Կ', 'Հ', 'Ձ', 'Ղ', 'Ճ', 'Մ', 'Յ', 'Ն', 'Շ', 'Ո', 'Չ', 'Ռ', 'Ս', 'Վ', 'Տ', 'Ր', 'Ց', 'Պ', 'Փ', 'Ք',  'Ֆ']
    
# Print the first several training images, along with the labels
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
for i in range(36):  #36   

    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 12, i + 1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
    ax.imshow(np.squeeze(x_train[i])) #this line throws that error
    ax.set_title("{}".format(labels[y_train[i]]))
    
plt.show()
```

> Second issue

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

model = Sequential()
# First convolutional layer accepts image input
model.add(Conv2D(filters=5, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu', 
                        input_shape=(50, 50, 3)))
# Add a max pooling layer
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=4))
# Add a convolutional layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=15, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Add another max pooling layer
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=4))
# Flatten and feed to output layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

# Summarize the model
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train_OH,
            validation_split=0.20,
            epochs=2,
            batch_size=50)
```

Full Stack trace:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8468c80f3ad0> in <module>()
      3                 validation_split=0.20,
      4                 epochs=2,
----> 5                 batch_size=50)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1130             else:
   1131               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 810, in train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1665, in categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 4994, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 34, 3) and (None, 3) are incompatible
```

Comment: your x_train and y_train shapes are not matching

Comment: I see... My x_train is `(25, 50, 50, 3)` and my y_train is `(25,)` do you how can I match?

Comment: can you show what loss you used while model compiling?

Comment: I updated my code and I used `categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Hard to fix it without seeing the model, but your network outputs does not match the shape of `y_train` (`line 201, in __call__` in your stack trace). Btw, you claim `y_train` is `(25,)` but the error message tell us it's actually `(25, 3)`, while your model outputs something shaped as `(25, 34, 3)`. Hence, the categorical crossentropy cannot be computed.

Comment: i updated my code the `defining the model` I hope that helps

Comment: @TheAppGuy21 Can you check your model output with `model.output_shape` and compare it to `y_train.shape` ? Do you get the same value as in the error message ? I feel like the issue is coming from data preparation, and `y_train` is not what it should be.

Comment: the `model.output_shape` returns `(None, 3)` and it does not match with my y_train. I think so to that is coming from data preparation

Comment: @NiziL I update my code... my first issue is how I prep my data that throws another error, that why  my model is not compiling properly. I temp fix my by doing `for i in range(26):` but I have 36 images that I want to get all my images. How can I fix this for issue 1?

Comment: @TheAppGuy21 you have used `y_train_OH`. can you show what it looks like?

Comment: well right now `y_train_OH` shows ` [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]`

Comment: Can you please share the entire code(if it is shareable) and also, help us to know what the dataset looks like. As in the first issue, you have 35 categories of label , but you are defining 3 label categories in last dense layer in the second issue. What is the value of x_train.shape, y_train_OH.shape?